# How to replace multiple occurrences of innerHTML of a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

For a div that appears multiple times in your HTML :

```
<div class="myclass">abc</div>
<div class="myclass">abc def</div>
...
```

How can I achieve the replacement of "abc" for all the occurrences ? 
(I found resources to replace the first occurrence but not the rest)

This is my code with javascript method

```
<script>
 function addLoadEvent(func) {
   var oldonload = window.onload;
   if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
     window.onload = func;
   } else {
     window.onload = function() {
       if (oldonload) {
         oldonload();
       }
       func();
     }
   }
 } 

 addLoadEvent(function() {  

    oldText = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").innerHTML; 
    for (i = 0; i<oldText.length; i++){ 
    newText = oldText[i].innerHTML;
    newText = newText.replace(/abc/g, "123");
    oldText[i].innerHTML = newText;

    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is literally no jquery in that example? It's vanilla javascript but your also loading jquery for no reason! What exactly is the question here, does that not work?

Comment: yes it is not working, i am trying to find a good method to replace the inner text in the div that occurs multiple times. Maybe I confused myself between jquery and JS...

Comment: Your code works, just remove `.innerHTML` from `document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")`

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution:

The problem is at this line: `oldText = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass").innerHTML;`

`.innerHTML` method returns `HTML` content.

You only need to get elements by class name, and obtain a `nodeList`.

```
oldText = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");
```

```js
function addLoadEvent(func) {
   var oldonload = window.onload;
   if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
     window.onload = func;
   } else {
     window.onload = function() {
       if (oldonload) {
         oldonload();
       }
       func();
     }
   }
 }
 addLoadEvent(function() {  
    oldText = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass"); 
    for (i = 0; i<oldText.length; i++){ 
      newText = oldText[i].innerHTML;
      newText = newText.replace(/abc/g, "123");
      oldText[i].innerHTML = newText;
    }
 });
```

```html
<div class="myclass">abc</div>
<div class="myclass">abc def</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

target every class, split value, remove 0 index and concatenate.

```
  $('.myclass').each(function(){
       var data = $(this).val();
       var data_array = data.split();
       var new = '';
       for(var i=1; i<data_array.length; i++){
          var _new += ' '+data_array[i];
       }
       $(this).val(_new);
    });
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants jquery. He doesn't know what it is

Comment: `new` is a keyword and cannot be used as a variable name.